# Angular Firebase database value Id product.key(productId) is showing undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database

[image items/undefined its not true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLhFV.png)

I tried to follow a tutorial about Angular + Firebase but the version of the tutorial i am using angular 15, i find a lots answer but not work for me

Here is model/product.ts

```
export interface Product{
    key: string;
    data:any;
    title: string;
    price: number;
    category: string|null;
    imageUrl:string;
}
```

Here is product-card-component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../models/product';
import { ShoppingCartService } from '../shopping-cart.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'product-card',
  templateUrl: './product-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-card.component.css'] 
})
export class ProductCardComponent {
 
@Input('product') product: Product;
@Input('show-actions') showActions = true;
constructor(private cartService:ShoppingCartService){

}
addToCart(product:Product){
  this.cartService.addToCart(product);

}
}
```

Here is my shopping-cart.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
import { Product } from './models/product';
import {  take } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShoppingCartService {
  product:Product[] = [];
  constructor(private db:AngularFireDatabase) { }
 private create(){
    return this.db.list('/shopping-carts').push({
      dateCreated: new Date().getTime()
    });
  }

   private getCart(cartId:string){
     return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/'+cartId)
   }
 private getOrCreateCartId(){
     let cartId = localStorage.getItem('cartId');
    if(cartId) return cartId;
    this.create().then((result:any) => {
    localStorage.setItem('cartId',result.key);
    return result.key;
  })
 }
getItem(cartId: string, productId: string) {
    return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId + '/items/' + productId);
  }
  private async getOrCreateCartId() {
    const cartId = localStorage.getItem('cartId');
    if (cartId) { return cartId; }
    let result = await this.create() as any;
    localStorage.setItem('cartId', result.key);
    return result.key;
}
  async addToCart(product:Product){
      let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
      let item$ = this.getItem(cartId, product.key);
        console.log(product.key); // showing undefined
      item$.snapshotChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe((item:any) => {
          if (item.payload.exists()) {
           item$.update({ quantity: item.payload.val().quantity + 1 })
                  }
                  else{
                    item$.set({product:product,quantity: 1})
                  }
                });
}
}
```

I dont know why product.key is showing undefined

Comment: in product-card-component.ts `@Input('product') product: Product;` seems to receive product with `key` undefined. Maybe when you pass `product` into `<product-cart>` it is already has `key` = undefined

Comment: in `<product-cart>` i can get data{category,image,price,title } key{ } is id   so how to get product  id ?

Comment: where do you call `addToCart()` of your component? What do you pass inside this method?

Comment: `async addToCart(product:Product)` Product is interface{ key: string;data: string;title: string;  price: number; category: string|null;  imageUrl:string;} but key can not read

Comment: getAll products i use snapshotvalueChange so when show all product, console.log object is [ data{title,price,category,imageUrl} , key{ } ],so that when i call key in shopping-cart.service its undefined beacause interface Product not have key , i dont know how to get key

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: but i have notify "Sorry, we are no longer accepting answers from your account.." so i can not add answer, i'm newbie so pardon me so how long can unban sir